# how do I detect what may root view binding layout is

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-viewbinding

I am building an android activity that changes between three different layouts, using view binding and Kotlin. Each layout has its own binding object. how can I detect from the Kotlin code which layout is being displayed?

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var constrainBinding: ActivityMainBinding // constrain layout
    lateinit var linearBinding: MainMenuBinding // linear layout
    lateinit var tableBinding: TableLayoutBinding // table layout

    var linearLayout = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        constrainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        linearBinding = MainMenuBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        tableBinding = TableLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(linearBinding.root)

        linearBinding.btConstrain.setOnClickListener { loadConstraintLayout() }
        linearBinding.btTable.setOnClickListener { loadTableLayout() }

        constrainBinding.tvBack.setOnClickListener { loadLinearLayout() }
    }
```

Comment: The normal way of changing what is displayed in Android is to use different fragments, or to change visibility of views within a single layout. Is there a reason you are trying to do it this way? How are you actually changing the layout? (can you add the `loadX` methods to the question?)

Comment: You should have three activities that each uses its binding, then navigate between them, or use fragments as @TylerV mentioned.

Comment: That's not the right way to do it . You will be consuming extra memory and also its had to handle navigation in this . Use Fragments instead .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this three layouts instead of three fragments,
you could add a var to the current Binding:

```
    lateinit var currentBinding: ViewBinding

    private fun loadLinearLayout() {
        currentBinding = linearBinding
    }

    private fun loadTableLayout() {
        currentBinding = tableBinding
    }

    private fun loadConstraintLayout() {
        currentBinding = constrainBinding
    }
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to upvote the answer :)